# How track the original URL before we redirect them using Akamai?

Tags: redirect, akamai

We use Akamai for redirect. I would like to track the original URL for the analytics tracking.How can we do that? Do we have any provision in akamai to do that? Any direction on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can print referrer url in logs which will give you the original URL before redirect, assuming you are not doing multiple redirects for for example A-> B-> C.